Automation Testing: Unable to Find and Interact with Elements Inside Flutter's Shadow Root (open)
I’m currently trying to perform automation testing on a Flutter app but am facing an issue: I’m unable to locate any elements or fields in the browser’s Developer Tools element panel, even though the fields are visible in the UI.
The app uses Shadow-root (open), and while I can see the shadow root, none of the actual elements or fields inside it are visible.
I’m using Playwright for testing and have also tried using Chrome's ruler to determine the position of the elements. However, this didn’t work either, as the ruler only detects the position of the Shadow DOM or shadow root container and not the actual fields or components inside it.
Does anyone know how I can successfully achieve this testing? Are there any workarounds or specific approaches for testing Flutter apps effectively in such cases?
Additional Details:
I do not have access to the Flutter app's source code.
Below is the only visible code snippet I can see in the Developer Tools:
<flt-glass-pane style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; cursor: default;">
  #shadow-root (open)
  <style></style>
  <flt-semantics-placeholder role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enable accessibility" style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -1px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></flt-semantics-placeholder>
  <flt-scene-host style="pointer-events: none;">
    <flt-scene>
      <flt-canvas-container>
        <canvas width="1850" height="902" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 1480px; height: 721.6px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);" class=""></canvas>
      </flt-canvas-container>
    </flt-scene>
  </flt-scene-host>
  <flt-semantics-host style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: scale(0.8);"></flt-semantics-host>
<style id="__web-inspector-hide-shortcut-style__">
    .__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__, .__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ *, 
    .__web-inspector-hidebefore-shortcut__::before, .__web-inspector-hideafter-shortcut__::after {
      visibility: hidden !important;
    }
  </style>
</flt-glass-pane>

